# Why does chrome add specific properties to h* elements?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I wonder why Chrome adds style properties to heading elements of the `<h>` familiy.
When i add such a element, and do no specific css markup, the following is added by chrome:

```
h3 {
display: block;
font-size: 1.17em;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

i have to overwrite it with something like

```
h3{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0;
    cursor: default;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Okay, i can accept the part where they set it to bold and increase the font size, but why the hell do they change the margins?

I find this very confusing sometimes, as i rearrange said elements and wonder why the behaviour of `<p>` and `<h>` is different because i forget about this.

Or is it just me and i am missing the important part?

Excuse my english, tried my best.

Comment: Use a simple CSS reset. It will solve these problems

Comment: `margin:0` should also work

Comment: i already do, but seems it is a little outdated. Of course your right, but have this said, i still wonder about the subject

Comment: Most browsers set defaults. A reset.css style sheet is the preferred method to override this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desactivate CSS: you'll understand why browsers have a default stylesheet (of their choice).

- Just imagine a list in a list in a list without any `padding/margin-left` set on items: all list items whatever their level would be left-aligned and very difficult to read.
- without 1em of margin between `p`, you couldn't tell if 2 group of sentences are in two different paragraphs or just separated by a `<br>` (that and collapsing margins... vertically only)
- `a` are underlined by default and have this blue color we are so accustomed to. How would you tell there are links in a text if they weren(t underlined and black?

All this define a *natural* display of text, that was necessary with plain HTML before Lie and Bos invented CSS.

As for `-start`, `-end`, `-before` and `-after` suffixes, this is just a CSS3 *agnostic* way of expressing top, right, bottom and left. What I mean by agnostic is the language may be `RTL` (written right to left like arabic and hebrew) or `LTR` (left to right like english or french) or one day from top to bottom and *lines* from left to right, whatever the main direction and secondary direction, you can say *before* and the browser will understand from context if it's top or left...
But that's the internals of the browsers: of course the `margin` instruction is unprefixed and if you don't even care about RTL languages, it'll work with TRBL for a *long* time ;)
So just continue with simple things like

```
margin: 1em 10px 1.333em 20px
```

edit:
Definitions from [CSS Writing Modes Module Level 3 - Flow-relative Directions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/#logical-directions):

> The flow-relative directions, **before, after**, start, and end, are defined relative to the flow of content on the page. In an LTR ‘horizontal-tb’ writing mode, they correspond to the **top, bottom**, left, and right directions, respectively.

Comment: You're welcome. Inspector/Firebug-like tools would be simpler to use if they had an Advanced mode where they'd show these `-webkit-*-end` but still show those related to forms like `-webkit-appearance` in "simple" mode...